# Doing a SQL insert without having to look up a value in another table first

Tags: sql, mysql

Imagine I have two tables:

- PETS
- SPECIES

The `SPECIES` table has two columns:

- ID - Species ID Number
- DESCRIPTION - Description of the species (DOG, CAT, TURTLE, etc.)

The `PETS` table has two columns:

- NAME - Name of the pet
- SPECIES a link to the `ID` field of the `SPECIES` table

If I want a list of all pets named `FLUFFY` who are cats, I can do the following in *a single SQL statement*:

```
select *
from NAME, SPECIES
where PETS.NAME = 'FLUFFY' 
    and SPECIES.DESCRIPTION = 'CATS'
    and PETS.SPECIES = SPECIES.ID
```

Now, I have a new pet, `BOWSER`, who's a dog. I want to be able to say something like this:

```
INSERT INTO PETS
    (PETS.NAME, SPECIES.DESCRIPTION)
VALUES
    ('BOWSER', 'DOG')
```

Yes, I know I can first find the `SPECIES.ID` for `DOG`, then do the insert:

```
my $species = $sql.execute(select ID from SPECIES where description = 'DOG');
insert into PETS (NAME, SPECIES)
values ('BOWSER', '$species')
```

But, I want to do the insert with in *a single SQL statement* much the way I could do my query. Is that possible?

Comment: I had a dog called Bowser, awesome dog name.  Anyway, you probably want to be careful here if you encounter a scenario where no species exists in the table for the pet you are inserting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
INSERT INTO Pets(Name, Species)
    SELECT 'Bowser' AS Name, ID AS Species
      FROM Species
     WHERE Description = 'DOG';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subselect like:

```
INSERT INTO Pets (
    Name,
    Species
) VALUES (
    'Bowser',
    (SELECT Id FROM Species WHERE Description='Dog')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO PETS
(
    NAME, 
    SPECIES
)
SELECT
    'BOWSER',
    ID
FROM 
    SPECIES
WHERE
    DESCRIPTION='DOG'
```